# Why does my pet cast electric shocks?

Tags: torchlight

This is a screenshot of my pet (a former cat, now permanently transmogrified into a Mimic) shortly after triggering an outburst of lightning.

[image]

Please note that:

- My character is not doing anything.
- Mimics, as far as I know, do not cast electric shocks (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).
- According to the Pet sheet, my pet inflicts zero elemental damage.

I don't know much about the inner workings of Torchlight, but I suspect a few factors:

- My pet has an amulet equipped which increases its electric damage by 3%.
- My currently equipped weapon inflicts electric damage.
- My pet was a Burrower at some point, and Burrowers do cast electric shocks.

Which one(s) is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the first option. It's a [critical hit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Torchlight/comments/1ald50/elemental_status_effects_mechanics/). This in turn causes the [shock effect](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Elements) when the crit activates and electrical is the dominant element since you've not stated that you've any other elements on the pet. Crit effects are always cast as the dominant (plurality) element.